# Is there other ways to track data except using global variable in php?

Tags: php

I would like to use a variable to keep data, and then when there is new data comes, it can be used to compare if the new data equals previous data.

I know set a global variable can be used to do it. But some documents said it is not good to use global variable in php, should try to avoid to use global variable.

Is there any other ways to solve the tracking data problem?

Comment: Global !== persistent, it sounds as though you want to keep your data persistent

Comment: persistent data would require db or file storage

Comment: Any variable "keeps data", that's basically what a variable is. You'll need to be more specific about where this data needs to be written to and from. For instance, if you are comparing results of two calls to an API, you might create a class that represents the API connection, and pass around one object of that class which can be used for multiple calls. But that may be nothing like your situation, I have no idea.

Comment: @IMSoP the data comes from an ajax call after i click a button on a page. I think i can only use db to do this, right? Cause every clicking is a new call, no matter using static and global variable, the previous data can not be kept. Cause all the variables are cleared automatically by the php garbage collection mechanism when current ajax call is complete.

Comment: @Will Sounds like you need to read up on "sessions" - tracking values for a particular user by sending them an identifying cookie.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use static properties for these purposes

```
class Globals {
    public static $test = 0;
}
```

and access it like this:

```
Globals::$test = 1;
```

or

```
echo Globals::$test;
```

Comment: Note that this has many of the same disadvantages as a global variable. Ideally, the design of the application should mean you're not reliant on such centralised data.